# Customize color pallets widget

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, color, qgis-customization, qgis-custom-widgets

I use some color palettes (1) that I added through QGIS settings and I would like to know if it is possible to customize how these palettes are displayed in the Layers Properties or any popup widget for color selection. More specifically, the width of the columns or the number of "pixel" colors displayed in a row. By default, QGIS shows this way:

[image]

My goal is to have a better visulization as shown below:

[image]

(1) https://www.davidrevoy.com/article27/palettes-for-gimp-mypaint-or-krita